# Finding function next value in a specific column

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to make a macro button that will automatically select column H and then search and select one by one in an array(one every time I click the macro) every cell in that specific column, that contains the € symbol. I can do that exactly as I want manually using the native excel search function but it is time consuming. Yet I don't know how to do that in VBA. Note that the cells in column H are currency formatted..The code that almost works for me so far is this:

```
Search = InStr(ActiveCell.NumberFormat, Chr(128))

Selection.Find(What:=Search, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, _
LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
```

BUT the above code **doesn't automatically select column H for search**. I have to do that manually. When i insert in the above code `Columns("H").Select` (in order to make the code select the column H automatically) the macro selects the first cell that contains the € symbol in the column H (which is what i want) BUT when clicking again it does not go to the NEXT cell that contains the € symbol in that column. It sticks on the first finding. Could you please help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA find macro stops working when search range included in code - Please advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48643712/vba-find-macro-stops-working-when-search-range-included-in-code-please-advice)

Answer (score 1):

You should always avoid using `Selection.` or `.Select`.

Instead of `Selection.Find` specify the correct range:

`Worksheets("MySheetName").Columns("H").Find`

Also have a look at the [Range.FindNext Method (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-findnext-method-excel). With find you will always find the first occurrence only. For further searches you will need to use FindNext.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what do you want to achieve, but if you need to find cells formatted as Currency, I would rather use this code:

```
Sub findCur()
    Dim rngCol As Range
    Set rngCol = Range("H:H")

    With Application.FindFormat
        .Clear
        .NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"
    End With
    rngCol.Find(What:="*", After:=ActiveCell, SearchFormat:=True).Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a condition to the selection, something like:

```
If Selection.Column<>7 then Columns("H").select
```

This way if you are already in column H, it won't reselect it, but if you are not there, it will go there.

Comment: Very bad practice to use `.Select` if you can use column H directly.